# Error "connection closed" en el acceso SSH a CentOS 7

Tags: linux, bash, centos, ssh

Estoy iniciándome en la gestión de un **servidor** en este caso, `CentOS 7`.

Después de haber usado durante unos días un usuario que accedía bien desde `SSH` y `SFTP`, he perdido todo acceso al servidor.

He estado leyendo en varios foros, y he llevado a cabo algunos cambios -de permisos, principalmente, entrando a través de la consola `KVM`; pero nada funciona.

Al acceder via `SSH` por Terminal, sigo recibiendo este mensaje:

> /bin/bash: No such file or directory
>
> Connection to 82.223.110.102 closed

Agradezco toda ayuda que permita salir de este bloqueo.

Gracias y saludos!!

Comment: @Travv la [edición que sugeriste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/76921) no creo que esté aportando nada relevante. Negritas o backticks (`) no aportan legibilidad y, francamente, parece que lían más. Lee [¿Qué formato deberían tener los nombres de tecnologías/lenguajes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/448/83) y [¿Cuándo debería editar publicaciones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) para más detalles, gracias.

Comment: emmatr: tiene pinta de que el usuario con el que accedías tiene definido /bin/bash como su shell (esto se define al hacer `useradd` y se ve en `/etc/passwd`). Sin embargo, por algún motivo Bash no está allí, sino en otra ruta y no te deja usarlo. ¿Puedes acceder con otro usuario? De lo contrario deberás acceder al servidor en [rescue mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RescueMode) y hacer los cambios.

Comment: Muchas gracias fedorqui. He entrado a /etc/passwd y parece que está todo bien y sí existe bash en la ruta: user:x:1000:1000::/home/user:/bin/bash Sin embargo, he entrado con un segundo usuario y está ocurriendo lo mismo: no bash directory y connection closed. Si entro en rescue mode, ¿qué cambios debo hacer?

Comment: emmatr: ¿pero entonces la ruta /bin/bash sí existe?

Comment: fedorqui: si entro en /etc/passwd, una de las líneas contiene este texto: user:x:1000:1000::/home/user:/bin/bash  Entiendo que significa que sí existe esta ruta.

Comment: No, no tiene porqué existir. Si tú haces `ls -l /bin/bash`, ¿te lo encuentra? Lo digo porque me parece que el problema reside en que intenta acceder a bash usando una ruta incorrecta. Para saber dónde está realmente Bash, utiliza `which bash` y la ruta que te dé añádela a ese usuario con `usermod -s <esa ruta> <el usuario>` (hazlo así, no modifiques `/etc/passwd` a mano).

Comment: Gracias. Sigo lo que indicas, pero el sistema primero dice que no exite este directorio y, al preguntarle which bash, devuelve la misma ruta que dice que no exite: /bin/bash

Comment: ¿Qué cambios de permisos has llevado a cabo? ¿Puedes poner que permisos tiene el ejecutable /bin/bash? Viendo que has accedido a /etc/passw quiere decir que tienes acceso al servidor sin ser con una conexión ssh ¿no? ¿entonces puedes ejecutar bash?

Comment: Gracias B. Pato. Finalmente reseteé el servidor y logré acceder creando nuevos usuarios y manteniendo rutas habituales.

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco el lugar que buscas esta en:

/usr/bin/bash

pero no es un directorio si no un archivo pero es donde inicia los procesos de bash algo asi como el rc.local

Intenta poner esa ruta a ver que te dice

Comment: Gracias, Jebux. Está funcionando ya el acceso siguiendo esta ruta.